# Using TestCase with fsunit

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013, fsunit

I have been trying to use fsunit to test a project.  If I limit myself to `[<TestMethod>]` methods they all show up in the TestExplorer.  However, if I try to use `[<TestCase(...)>]` nothing shows up and no tests get executed.

I expect I have something wrong in my setup but I have no clue as to what it could be.  I have NUnit.Framework as well as FsUnit referenced in my code.

This is using Visual Studio 2013, BTW.

An example of what I am trying to do (with a toy Factorial function):

```
open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

[<TestFixture>]
type ``Given the Fact function``()=

    [<TestCase(1,1)>]
    [<TestCase(2,2)>]
    [<TestCase(3,6)>]
    ...
    member t.``the result is calculated correctly``(n, expected) = 
        let actual = Fact n 
        actual |> should equal expected
```

I have tried replacing `TestFixture` with `TestClass` but this doesn't seem to do any good, either.

Mark

Comment: Try a different test runner. It works for me with testdriven.net.

Answer (score 3):

I got the question answered by Tomas Petricek in an email exchange.  It turns out that I had to do more than download the NUnit and FsUnit frameworks to make this work.  I also had to download and install the [NUnit VsTestAdapter](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.2) to make it work with the MS testing framework.

This information was actually on the NUnit web site but I just didn't know where to look to find it.

Thanks, Tomas.

Comment: Thanks for the general direction.  I've added a link for completeness